# Is it possible to generate a Box upload embed widget via the API?

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I'd like to programmatically create Box.com upload embed widgets for specific folders for our account. It looks like it is possible to create a shared link: https://box-content.readme.io/#create-a-shared-link-for-a-folder

But I don't see any way do this in the API:

[image]

I've looked at the requests the above webpage is sending to create the widget and it looks like I could recreate them, but it would be nice to not have to rely on something that isn't documented.  It doesn't look like the widget generation page is using the 2.0 API.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to create a Box Upload widget via the API you can create a Box Embed window via the API (check out the documentation here: https://developers.box.com/box-embed/)

This will give you an iframe that you can embed in your site for users to drag and drop content and upload to Box.